# My C++ code crashes while trying to calculate the sum of elements in table

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sum

I'm trying to calculate the sum of elements in table using int function. Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void wylosujLiczby ( int tablica[], int iRozmiar, int pocz, int kon )
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        srand( time ( NULL ) );
        tablica [ i ] = ( ( std::rand() % ( kon - pocz ) ) + pocz );
        i++;
    } while ( i < iRozmiar );
}

void wypiszLiczby ( int tablica[], int iRozmiar )
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Liczba nr " << i << ": " << tablica [ i ] << std::endl;
        i++;
    } while ( i < iRozmiar );
}

int obliczSume ( int tablica[], int iRozmiar )
{
    int i, suma = 0;
    do
    {
        suma += tablica[ i ];
        i++;
    } while ( i < iRozmiar );

    return suma;
}

int main()
{
    int tablica[ 999 ];
    wylosujLiczby( tablica, 999, 4, 10 );
    wypiszLiczby( tablica, 999 );
    int iSuma = obliczSume( tablica, 999 );
    std::cout << "Suma liczb wynosi: " << iSuma << std::endl;
    std::cout << tablica[ 991 ];
    return 0;
}
```

Using Codeblocks, it compiles properly, however application crashes after printing all the values. What mistake have I made?

Comment: You never initialise `i`.

Comment: srand( time ( NULL ) ); is in a loop.  You should call it once at the start of your main.

Comment: Also doing `srand( time ( NULL ) );` in a loop and drawing random numbers from it won't work. It will give you repeating "random numbers" since you seed the PRNG with the exact same value (time in seconds) over and over again. `rand()` is just a cheap LCG (linear congruence generator) with a seed.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt if at least a second has passed it will give different values :)

Comment: This `int i, suma = 0;` initializes `suma`, but not `i`. This would be easier to see if you used `for` loops instead of `do while`.

Comment: "int function"?

Comment: If this compiles propertly, then you have a problem. All compilers I know will issue a **warning message** for the `int i, suma = 0;` line. Chances are you are using some default warning level, which is often not good enough. Or you are actually getting the warning but are ignoring it, which is exactly as bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int i, suma = 0;
```

You need to set i = 0 as well:

```
int i = 0, suma = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Feel kind of silly for making such a mistake

Comment: The syntax is nasty. I definitely prefer a single declaration/definition per line. It's more verbose and much clearer.